# как редактировать страницу битрикс если нет панели управления?

Tags: битрикс

как редактировать страницу битрикс если нет панели управления?

Comment: через доступ к FTP/SFTP.

Answer (score 2):

На этот вопрос не возможно дать однозначный ответ. Все зависит от того, что конкретно на какой странице вы хотите редактировать. Для полноценного ответа вам лучше проштудировать официальные курсы битрикс. Контент-менеджер и Администратор базовый.

Если же вы просто "потеряли" панель управления: восстановите ее. Для этого после тега body (скорее всего в header.php шаблона сайта) вам необходимо вставить код

```
<div id="panel">
    <?$APPLICATION->ShowPanel();?>
</div>
```

Так же можете это сделать в редакторе в админке: Админка - Настройки - Настройки продукта - Сайты - Шаблоны Сайтов - Ваш шаблон на редактирование и там первая вкладка "Шаблон" имеет текстовое поле содержащая header.php и footer.php вместе.